# Auto rejection of media files in pre-commit

Tags: svn

I would like SVN to automatically reject certain file types (i.e. mp3, mp4, mpeg, avi, etc...). Can anyone provide me with instructions on how to do this with SVN?

Comment: Are you saying these files are being rejected when you try to save, or you want them to be rejected?

Comment: Yes, I want all these types of Media files to be rejected.

Comment: Let me rephrase my query - I would like SVN to automatically reject certain file types (i.e. mp3, mp4, mpeg, avi, etc...). Can anyone provide me with instructions on how to do this with SVN?

Comment: Do you want them outright banned from your repository, or just not added/shown for adding by default, with the option to add it anyway if you really want to?

Comment: Johnie & Ben : I want to restrict those file types and which can show a warning message to users about "these file types are not allowed to be saved on SVN repo.."

Comment: has someone any fix for this.. pls share oif any